# My Code Says No Value Given for one or more required parameters

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2010

```
NonDim DC As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\VPMDB.accdb")
        DC.Open()
        Dim sSql As String = "UPDATE [MEMBERS] SET [SURNAME] = ?,[ADRRESS] =? WHERE MID =?"
        Dim save As New OleDbCommand(sSql, DC)
        save.CommandText = sSql
        save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtSName.Text)
        save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtAdd.Text)
        save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtID.Text)
        save.ExecuteRNonQuery()


        MessageBox.Show("Record succesfully updated" + txtID.Text)
```

The error points on the line

```
    save.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I am trying to update a record matching the ID with `txtID.text` (text box) in the table `Members`

Comment: This happens when in your query there is a typo and Access engine cannot recognize one or more fields or table name. Look for example to your [ADRRESS]. Could it be [ADDRESS] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things you need to verify;

1. Your syntax being passed
2. The value being passed as parameters (might be empty)

For the 1st example, reading your query line, I can see `ADDRESS` being written as `ADRRESS`, which you need to confirm if it corresponds to your column name.

Secondly, to be on the safe side, do verify the values being passed, as the below exemple;

```
    If not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSName.Text) Then
      save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtSName.Text)
    Else
      save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", DbNull.Value)
    End if
```

Comment: Thank you, even for the Empty field conditional statement